# Pairs Trading Strategy Pandas Update Position Based on Price

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, trading

I am trying to run a trading pairs trading strategy and I am having trouble updating columns based on a condition. DataFrame looks like:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Stock A Price': [5,6,7,8,10],
                   'Stock B Price': [7,7,7,6,4]})
```

I wan't to create new columns: `df['Stock A Position']` and `df['Stock B Position']` that are updated according to the following strategy: `df['Stock A Position'] == 'LONG'`, `df['Stock B Position'] == 'SHORT'` if Stock A Price is less than Stock B and vice versa (short A and long B if price A>B). However, after a position is taken, both `df['Stock A Position']` and `df['Stock B Position']` should be updated as `'HOLD'` until the strategy condition is met again (prices cross paths).

Output should look like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Stock A Price': [5,6,7,8,10],
                   'Stock B Price': [7,7,7,6,4]
                   'Stock A Position': ['LONG', 'HOLD', 'HOLD', 'SHORT', 'HOLD']
                   'Stock B Position': ['SHORT', 'HOLD', 'HOLD', 'LONG', 'HOLD]'})
```

For instance, A position is long and B position is short for first row since Stock A Price = 5 < Stock B Price = 7. The next row A is still cheaper (6 vs. 7) so hold for both. Third, they are the same so continue to hold. Fourth, this is where stocks cross (since now A=8 > B=6) so now change position: short A and long B. Fifth, stock A still higher than B so hold.

Please let me know how to do this efficiently and be able to handle a large DataFrame. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by comparing the two columns (`A Price` and `B Price`) following your condition, then use the result to compare row pairs to discover where the price has changed. Create a variable to hold an offset that will save the `positions` for that column, then `map` the values obtained in the previous step into the columns.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Stock A Price': [5, 6, 7, 8, 10],
                'Stock B Price': [7, 7, 7, 6, 4]})


stg = df.iloc[:, 0] <= df.iloc[:, 1]
# create offset for "HOLD" status
to_map = stg + stg.eq(stg.shift()) * 2
to_map = to_map.clip(0, 2)

df['Stock A Position'] = to_map.map(lambda r: ["SHORT", "LONG", "HOLD"][r])
df['Stock B Position'] = to_map.map(lambda r: ["LONG", "SHORT", "HOLD"][r])

print(df)
```

Output from **df**

```
   Stock A Price  Stock B Price Stock A Position Stock B Position
0              5              7             LONG            SHORT
1              6              7             HOLD             HOLD
2              7              7             HOLD             HOLD
3              8              6            SHORT             LONG
4             10              4             HOLD             HOLD
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works great